# Randomly fading in each element of a matched set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to fade in each element so they randomly appear instead of 0,1,2,3...

I though about generating a random array and then trying to do the fades like this but that clearly doesn't work. Can anyone advise the best method of doing this?

I was thinking that picking out of a random array would be best since the same index number cant be selected twice?

My current attempt:

JS

```
var testArray = [3,2,6,4,0,1,5];
var $li = $('li').hide();


$li.each(function(i){

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.eq(testArray[i]).fadeIn(i*100);    

});​
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGC9f/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will fade in all the blocks at the same time:

```
var testArray = [3, 2, 6, 4, 0, 1, 5];
var $li = $('li').hide();

for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    $li.eq(testArray[i]).fadeIn(i * 1000);
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YGC9f/3/

---

This will fade in blocks one by one:

```
var testArray = [3, 2, 6, 4, 0, 1, 5];
var $li = $('li').hide();

for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $li.eq(testArray[i]).fadeIn(1000);
        }, i * 1000);
    })(i);
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YGC9f/6/

Comment: say if I want to do something after the last li has faded in, where could I add that?

Comment: in your first solution, basically i would like to run some new code once the final image has faded in?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var testArray = [3,2,6,4,0,1,5];
$('li').hide();
$('li').each(function(i){
    $('li').eq(testArray[i]).fadeIn(i*1000);  
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/776eV/1/

**Update**

---

And heres a better version which is truely random (using John Resig array remove method):

http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/cUge9/3/

Answer (score 0):

Using VisioN's answer as starting material, you can create a random array like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YGC9f/7/

```
var testArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var tmp, current, top = testArray.length;
  if(top) while(--top) {
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
    tmp = testArray [current];
    testArray [current] = testArray [top];
    testArray [top] = tmp;
  }
var $li = $('li').hide();

for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    $li.eq(testArray[i]).fadeIn(i * 1000);
}​
```